# Smarty If URL Contains

Tags: php, smarty, x-cart

Using Smarty Tags I'd like to determine if an URL contains a word, something like:

```
{if $smarty.get.page contains "product.php"} .....
```

I know contains doesn't exist, but how could I easily go about writing something similar to achieve the above code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `strpos` to check if a string has another string inside of it.

```
$pos = strpos($smarty.get.page, "product.php");

if($pos !== false) {
 // found, do something
}
```

Except you need to wrap it in `{php}` and `{/php}`.

`$smarty.get.page` translates to `$_GET['page']`, so you could replace it with the GET variable as well.

Comment: I will try this but I believe it may not work unless strpos is a smarty code method - thank you for the reply

Comment: It will work, as `strpos` is a PHP method. Good luck, and feel free to accept if it works :)

Comment: @Loren forgot to tag you, sorry

Comment: I have tried this using smarty tags w/ no success - i appreciate your effort however, I believe that strpos is not a supported smarty method -thanks so much for your time

Comment: @Loren What do you currently have as your code? Smarty is a PHP extension, and is `$smarty.get.page` a string?

Comment: I am using TPL files that contain the smarty code currently - my code i tested was {if strpos($smarty.get.page, 'product.php') > 0} ..etc etc etc.. {/if}

Comment: @Loren see my edit; just wrap exactly what I have in `{php}` and `{/php}` and it should work :)

Comment: ok great - this is looking like i'm getting closer - is there something special i would need to do if i'm outputting a string where the //found, do something

Comment: for example, if the statement isn't false i need to output some javascript code in between the if($pos !== false) {
 // ouput javascript here
}

Comment: Should be able to use `echo` :) --> `echo $my_var;`

Comment: its pretty insane javascript - autogenerated by google for their website optimizer - i'm basically a/b testing two product pages, is there an alternative to the echo as it has many lines and i would have to modify the quotes and stuff =) not sure if i can somehow just output it like u know in PHP how u can like do something like <? if ( 1 == 1 ) { ?> my string output <? } <?>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5378/discussion-between-loren-and-tekknolagi)

Answer (score 28):

> All PHP conditionals and functions are recognized, such as ||, or, &&, and, is_array(), etc.

`{if strpos($smarty.get.page, "product.php") !== false}`

Comment: this worked very well but i had to accept tekk becuase he spent so much time helping me, but thank you so much for your help as well