# How to search string in given string in smarty

Tags: smarty, string-function

I am using below code to search string in given string  in smarty but below code not working

```js
$MyError = "Attribute";
{if $MyError|strpos:'Attribute Registration Number with value'} 
<p>Welcome</p>
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Smarty, you can use the PHP function *strpos* to search a string in given string :

```
{if strpos('Attribute Registration Number with value', $MyError) !== false}
  <p>Welcome</p>
{/if}
```

Here is [an other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8281105/6444651) about it.

Comment: How did you define your variable? If you want to define the variable directly in your template, you should use the {assign} tag like {assign var=&quot;MyError&quot; value=&quot;Attribute&quot;} (see more: http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.assign.tpl)